# How to get HTTPS endpoints to proxy successfully in WireMock?

Tags: java, https, http-proxy, wiremock

I am writing an HTTP record-playback proxy which internally uses WireMock, and am having a problem with recording HTTPS targets. HTTP sites work fine.

Here is how I set up the WireMock proxy for an unencrypted site:

```
java \
    -jar /var/proximate/wiremock-standalone-2.4.1.jar \
    --port 9000 \
    --proxy-all http://ilovephp.jondh.me.uk \
    --record-mappings \
    --root-dir /remote/experiment/record/http
```

I then can record anything on that site using this command:

```
wget -e use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=proximate-proxy:9000 \
    http://ilovephp.jondh.me.uk/en/tutorial/make-your-own-blog
```

In short order I will get some automatically created mappings:

```
/ # ls -R /remote/experiment/record/http
/remote/experiment/record/http:
__files   mappings

/remote/experiment/record/http/__files:
body-tutorial-make-your-own-blog-tWrNm.txt

/remote/experiment/record/http/mappings:
mapping-tutorial-make-your-own-blog-tWrNm.json
```

Here is much the same thing, but on an SSL site. Proxy first:

```
java \
    -jar /var/proximate/wiremock-standalone-2.4.1.jar \
    --port 9000 \
    --proxy-all https://www.rottentomatoes.com/ \
    --record-mappings \
    --root-dir /remote/experiment/record/https \
    --verbose
```

And here is the fetch:

```
wget -e use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=proximate-proxy:9000 \
    https://www.rottentomatoes.com/
```

The result from WireMock is that the internal cache directories are created, but they do not contain anything:

```
/ # ls -R /remote/experiment/record/https
/remote/experiment/record/https:
__files   mappings

/remote/experiment/record/https/__files:

/remote/experiment/record/https/mappings:
```

I am using WM 2.4.1 on Alpine 3.4 in a Docker container. Do I need to use some of the `https`-specific command line switches to get this to work?

### Update

I was temporarily heartened to see that recent release [2.5.0](https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/releases/tag/2.5.0) had a recent merge of `https-bind-address-bug`, which sounded very relevant. I have tried with this release, but unfortunately it makes no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is partly solved - my main error was that the proxy address for HTTPS connections is set separately, for both WireMock and the client. I am now using:

```
java \
    -jar /var/proximate/wiremock-standalone-2.4.1.jar \
    --port 9000 \
    --https-port 9050 \
    --proxy-all https://www.rottentomatoes.com/ \
    --record-mappings \
    --root-dir /remote/experiment/record/https \
    --verbose \
    --print-all-network-traffic
```

I've added `--print-all-network-traffic` so I can see if any HTTPS traffic is hitting the proxy at all (it is now).

Here is the new client command, complete with new proxy directive:

```
wget -e use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=proximate-proxy:9000 \
     -e https_proxy=proximate-proxy:9050 \
     --verbose \
     --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0" \
     https://www.rottentomatoes.com/
```

However, now the proxy is actually being used, it looks like the operation is not completing successfully. I've tried other encrypted sites and received the same vague errors:

```
Resolving proximate-proxy... 172.18.0.2
Connecting to proximate-proxy|172.18.0.2|:9050... connected.
Failed reading proxy response: No error information
Retrying.

--2017-01-26 09:20:18--  (try: 2)  https://www.rottentomatoes.com/
Connecting to proximate-proxy|172.18.0.2|:9050... connected.
Failed reading proxy response: No error information
Retrying.

--2017-01-26 09:20:20--  (try: 3)  https://www.rottentomatoes.com/
Connecting to proximate-proxy|172.18.0.2|:9050... connected.
Failed reading proxy response: No error information
Retrying.

^C
```

I have replaced the user agent in case there is some third-party rejection based on the standard "wget" string, but this does not seem to affect things either.

I will ask a new question about this, to narrow down whether this is a WireMock or a Wget problem.